# Arrays in Python are assigned by value or by reference?

Tags: python, arrays

I am wondering why when I delete the original array it affects the copied array:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr1 = arr
del arr[:]
print(arr1) #this prints []
```

but when I modify the elements of the original array there is no effect on the copied array:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr1 = arr
arr = [4,5,6]
print(arr1) #this prints [1,2,3]
```

If someone can explain this issue I appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Except you didn't modify the elements of the original array, you re-assigned to the variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: That is a list. Regardless, *every* variable in Python is essentially an object reference.

Answer (score 7):

You did not modify the elements of the original array, but rather re-assigned a new list to the `arr` variable. Your intuition of thinking changes to elements would be reflected in `arr1` if you properly accessed its elements is indeed true as lists are *mutable* in Python. For instance,

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr1 = arr
arr[1] = 4
print(arr1) #this prints [1,4,3]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to copy an array, but

```
arr1 = arr
```

is not one of them (in `C`-speak, that is just an aliased pointer). Try one of

```
arr1 = arr[:]  # slice that includes all elements, i.e. a shallow copy
arr1 = copy.copy(arr)  # from the copy module, does a shallow copy
arr1 = copy.deepcopy(arr)  # you guessed it.. ;-)
```

after any of those you will see that changes to `arr1` and `arr` are independent (of course if you're using a shallow copy then the items *in* the list will be shared).

Answer (score 3):

Objects in python would be considered to be passed by reference. It's a bit different than that, however.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
```

This statement does two things. First it creates a list object in memory; second it points the "arr" label to this object.

```
arr1 = arr
```

This statement creates a new label "arr1" and points it to the same list object pointed to by arr.

Now in your original code you did this:

```
del arr[:]
```

This deleted the elements of the list object and now any label pointing to it will point to an empty list. In your second batch of code you did this:

```
arr = [4, 5, 6]
```

This created a new list object in memory, and pointed the "arr" label to it. Now you have two list objects in memory, each being pointed to by two different labels. I just checked on my console, and arr points to [4,5,6] and arr1 to [1,2,3].

Here is a good post about it: http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Answer (score -3):

You did not do a full copy of the list, instead you just re-assigned the variable name.

In order to make a deep-copy of the list do the following:

```
arr1 = [x for x in arr]
```