# python list cleared while clearing another list

Tags: python, list

I'm currently writing a python skript and I have an issue that a list is getting cleared if I clear another list.

elements is a list that is filled before

```
elements2 = elements
while len(elements2) > 0:
    
    elements2.clear()
    print(elements)
    function(elements, elements2)
```

When i print elements the list is empty. This is critical because my function has a for-loop going through elements and putting some parts of the list in elements2 in some occasions so the funtion stops being declared only when all Parameters are set for it.

Why is elements cleared when I clear elements2 and how do i prevent it but still clear elements2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `elements2 = elements` does not make a copy of `elements`. You need to explicitly call the `.copy()` method: `elements2 = elements.copy()` for a (shallow) copy

Comment: python arrays are assigned by reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770791/arrays-in-python-are-assigned-by-value-or-by-reference

Answer (score 1):

when you assign `elements2` to `elements` you aren't copying the list instead `elements2` references the same list as elements so changes to one affects the other. Use:

```
elements2 = elements.copy()
```

to create a copy of the original

Answer (score 1):

Python lists are copied by reference, not by value. This means that when you set `elements2` equal to `elements`, you are setting them both to point to the same area in memory. That is why changes to `elements2` will also apply to `elements`. To combat this, you can use the `copy` module, or that you can use the following line to get the same result:
`elements2 = list(elements)`

This creates a copy of `elements`, but note that this isn't a deep copy - meaning that if `elements` contains lists or other types that are copied by reference, the values from both `elements` and `elements2` will point to the same object.